# How to check if IP is in one of these subnets

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, performance, subnet

I have ~12600 subnets:

eg. 123.123.208.0/20

and an IP.

I can use a SQLite Database or an array or whatever

There was a similar question asked about a month ago, however I am not looking for checking one IP against one subnet but a bunch of subnets (obviously the most efficient way, hopefully not O(total subnets)) :)

How can I check that the IP is one of in one of these subnets, I need true or false not the subnet if that helps optimisation.

There are similar subnets in the current list eg.:
(actual extract)

```
123.123.48.0/22 <-- not a typo
123.123.48.0/24 <-- not a typo
123.123.90.0/24
123.123.91.0/24
123.123.217.0/24
```

In total they range from 4.x.y.z to 222.x.y.z

Answer (score 29):

The best approach is IMO making use of bitwise operators. For example, `123.123.48.0/22` represents `(123<<24)+(123<<16)+(48<<8)+0` (=2071670784; this might be a negative number) as a 32 bit numeric IP address, and `-1<<(32-22)` = -1024 as a mask. With this, and likewise, your test IP address converted to a number, you can do:

```
(inputIP & testMask) == testIP
```

For example, 123.123.49.123 is in that range, as `2071671163 & -1024` is 2071670784

So, here are some tool functions:

```
function IPnumber(IPaddress) {
    var ip = IPaddress.match(/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$/);
    if(ip) {
        return (+ip[1]<<24) + (+ip[2]<<16) + (+ip[3]<<8) + (+ip[4]);
    }
    // else ... ?
    return null;
}

function IPmask(maskSize) {
    return -1<<(32-maskSize)
}
```

test:

```
(IPnumber('123.123.49.123') & IPmask('22')) == IPnumber('123.123.48.0')
```

yields `true`.

In case your mask is in the format '255.255.252.0', then you can use the IPnumber function for the mask, too.

Comment: I like your use of the bitwise operators, but does JavaScript guarantee your indian encoding? I broke out the ip range into low and high to allow for O(logN) behaviour when the columns are indexed as opposed to O(N) using this approach. But it may depend on sqlite's implementation. Not sure.

Comment: "guarantee endian encoding"? I don't see why it has to. It's just numbers. Anyway, you can indeed find both lower and upper bound of the range with IP&mask and with IP|~mask (~-1024==1023) respectively, so you can use BETWEEN to search for matches for the range.

Comment: @bart I have only input IP and mask, I want to check that input IP lies in the mask range or not ( mask in format 255.255.252.0 ) How to check that ?

Comment: One bug: if your subnet is not defined correctly with right side 0's, this will fail. To make bad definitions work, use (IPnumber('123.123.49.123') & IPmask('22')) == (IPnumber('123.123.48.1') & IPmask('22'))

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
var ip2long = function(ip){
    var components;

    if(components = ip.match(/^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$/))
    {
        var iplong = 0;
        var power  = 1;
        for(var i=4; i>=1; i-=1)
        {
            iplong += power * parseInt(components[i]);
            power  *= 256;
        }
        return iplong;
    }
    else return -1;
};

var inSubNet = function(ip, subnet)
{   
    var mask, base_ip, long_ip = ip2long(ip);
    if( (mask = subnet.match(/^(.*?)\/(\d{1,2})$/)) && ((base_ip=ip2long(mask[1])) >= 0) )
    {
        var freedom = Math.pow(2, 32 - parseInt(mask[2]));
        return (long_ip > base_ip) && (long_ip < base_ip + freedom - 1);
    }
    else return false;
};
```

Usage:

```
inSubNet('192.30.252.63', '192.30.252.0/22') => true
inSubNet('192.31.252.63', '192.30.252.0/22') => false
```

Comment: But your code doesn't include the first and the last IP.  
I added one more checking and now it does  
`return (long_ip > base_ip || long_ip === base_ip) && ((long_ip < base_ip + freedom - 1) || (long_ip === base_ip + freedom - 1));`

Answer (score 6):

I managed to solve this by using the [node netmask](https://github.com/rs/node-netmask) module.
You can check if an IP belongs to a subnet by making something like this:

```
import { Netmask } from 'netmask'

const block = new Netmask('123.123.208.0/20')
const ip = '123.123.208.0'
console.log(block.contains(ip))
```

Will here print `true`.

You can install it by using:

```
npm i --save netmask
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert the lower ip and the upper ip in the range to integers and store the range in the db then make sure both columns are indexed.

Off the top of my head (pseudo code):

```
function ipmap(w,x,y,z) {
  return 16777216*w + 65536*x + 256*y + z;
}

var masks = array[ipmap(128,0,0,0), ipmap(196,0,0,0), ..., ipmap(255,255,255,255)]

function lowrange(w, x, y, z, rangelength) {
  return ipmap(w, x, y, z) & masks[rangelength]
}

function hirange(w, x, y, z, rangelength) {
  return lowrange(w, x, y, z, ,rangelength) + ipmap(255,255,255,255) - masks[rangelength];
}
```

That ought to do it.

To find whether a particular ip falls in any of the ranges, convert it to an integer and do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ipranges WHERE lowrange <= 1234567 AND 1234567 <= highrange
```

The query optimizer should be able to speed this up greatly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how can I convert a subnet into a range using JavaScript? Also what about:
123.123.48.0/22
123.123.48.0/24

They overlap.

Comment: The start and end ips of the range will differ. so the overlap shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Isn't: 123.123.48.0/22: 123.123.48.1 - 123.123.51.254 & 123.123.48.0/24: 123.123.48.1 - 123.123.48.254

Comment: And the ends differ, so what's the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't a better solution remove the redundant /24? I guess I could always just take the lowest /x and remove all the higher subnets.

Comment: sure, but that's not part of your question.  The fact that they overlap is irrelevant, it'll just be slower.

Answer (score 2):

Functions `IPnumber` and `IPmask` are nice, however I would rather test like:

```
(IPnumber('123.123.49.123') & IPmask('22')) == (IPnumber('123.123.48.0')  & IPmask('22'))
```

Because for each address, you only need to take into account the network part of the address. Hence doing `IPmask('22')` will zero-out the computer part of the address and you should do the same with the network address.

Answer (score 1):

**Keywords**: Binary searching, preprocessing, sorting

I had a similar problem and binary search appears to be very efficient if you can pre-process your subnet list and sort it. Then you can achieve an asymptotic time complexity of **O(log n)**.

Here's my code (MIT License, original location: https://github.com/iBug/pac/blob/854289a674578d096f60241804f5893a3fa17523/code.js):

```js
function belongsToSubnet(host, list) {
  var ip = host.split(".").map(Number);
  ip = 0x1000000 * ip[0] + 0x10000 * ip[1] + 0x100 * ip[2] + ip[3];

  if (ip < list[0][0])
    return false;

  // Binary search
  var x = 0, y = list.length, middle;
  while (y - x > 1) {
    middle = Math.floor((x + y) / 2);
    if (list[middle][0] < ip)
      x = middle;
    else
      y = middle;
  }

  // Match
  var masked = ip & list[x][1];
  return (masked ^ list[x][0]) == 0;
}
```

And an example usage:

```js
function isLan(host) {
  return belongsToSubnet(host, LAN);
}

var LAN = [
  [0x0A000000, 0xFF000000], // 10.0.0.0/8
  [0x64400000, 0xFFC00000], // 100.64.0.0/10
  [0x7F000000, 0xFF000000], // 127.0.0.0/8
  [0xA9FE0000, 0xFFFF0000], // 169.254.0.0/16
  [0xAC100000, 0xFFF00000], // 172.16.0.0/12
  [0xC0A80000, 0xFFFF0000]  // 192.168.0.0/16
];
```

```js
isLan("127.12.34.56"); // => true
isLan("8.8.8.8"); // => false (Google's Public DNS)
```

You can [get a PAC script*](https://ibugone.com/project/pac-generator) and see how it performs (it loads a China IP list from somewhere else, sorts them and formats them appropriately) against 5000s of subnets. In practice its speed is surprisingly satisfactory.

The preprocessing code can be inspected using F12 Dev Tools on the above page. In short, you need to convert `1.2.3.4/16` to `[0x01020304, 0xFFFF0000]`, i.e. 32-bit unsigned integer for the IP address and network mask.

<sup>* Link goes to my personal website.</sup>

Comment: Your binary search misses the edge case where the list size is 1. Simply updating the loop to use `do { } while` syntax fixes this.

Comment: @this-sam I don't think so. When the list size is 1 it skips the loop with `x=0` and continues to apply subnet mask before checking equality. The binary search is intended to find the element `x` where `list[x] <= ip < list[x+1]`, so the only edge case is when `ip < list[0]` which has been handled earlier.

Comment: You are correct. I missed the preliminary check. In my implementation I also added a check for an empty input list.