# JavaScript Endian Encoding?

Tags: javascript, encoding, bit-manipulation, endianness

[A response on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503052/javascript-is-ip-in-one-of-these-subnets/503238#503238) got me thinking, does JavaScript guarantee a certain endian encoding across OSs and browsers?

Or put another way are bitwise shifts on integers "safe" in JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are safe. Although you're not getting the speed benefits you might hope for since JS bit operations are "[a hack](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference#quickIDX4)".

Comment: I read that link. I disagree with some of it. The bit about doing a ~0 seems misleading. You get 32 bits, it's just always signed.

Answer (score 37):

Shifting is safe, but your question is flawed because endianness doesn't affect bit-shift operations anyway. Shifting left is the same on big-endian and little-endian systems in all languages. (Shifting right can differ, but only due to interpretation of the sign bit, not the relative positions of any bits.)

Endianness only comes into play when you have the option of interpreting some block of memory as bytes or as larger integer values. In general, Javascript doesn't give you that option since you don't get access to arbitrary blocks of memory, especially not the blocks of memory occupied by variables. [Typed arrays](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/) offer views of data in an endian-sensitive way, but the ordering depends on the host system; it's not necessarily the same for all possible Javascript host environments.

Endianness describes *physical* storage order, not *logical* storage order. Logically, the rightmost bit is *always* the least significant bit. Whether that bit's byte is the one that resides at the lowest memory address is a completely separate issue, and it only matters when your language exposes such a concept as "lowest memory address," which Javascript does not. Typed arrays do, but then only within the context of typed arrays; they still don't offer access to the storage of arbitrary data.

Comment: Great answer, very insightful.

Answer (score 14):

Some of these answers are dated, because endianness *can* be relevant when using typed arrays! Consider:

```
var arr32 = new Uint32Array(1);
var arr8 = new Uint8Array(arr32.buffer);
arr32[0] = 255;
console.log(arr8[0], arr8[1], arr8[2], arr8[3]);
```

When I run this in Chrome's console, it yields `255 0 0 0`, indicating that my machine is little-endian. However, [typed arrays use the system endianness by default](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typedarray-objects), so you might see `0 0 0 255` instead if your machine is big-endian.

Comment: That indicates the typed arrays are little-endian on *your* machine, not universally.

Comment: You really think Chrome defers that to the local system? I find that a bit hard to swallow.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? That's pretty much [precisely what the draft spec says it should do](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/#2.1).

Comment: If you are still around, please update your answer with the note about local endianness. If you aren't, I might do it myself, if I remember.

Comment: I've updated this answer with the information in the comments. Thanks for the info, @MikeKeesey and @leewz! You helped me today :)

Answer (score 5):

ECMA Script does actually have a concept of an integer type but it is implicitly coerced to or from a double-precision floating-point value as necessary (if the number represented is too large or if it has a fractional component).

Many mainstream Javascript interpreters (SpiderMonkey is an example) take a shortcut in implementation and interpret all numeric values as doubles to avoid checking the actual native type of the value for each instruction. As a result of the implementation hack, bit operations are implemented as a cast to an integral type followed by a cast back to a double representation. It is therefore not a good idea to use bit-level operations in Javascript and you won't get a performance boost anyway.

Comment: I imagine in the long run some of the JIT engines could keep things in doubles if you're doing a bunch of bit-level stuff. Then, conceivably, it could be fast, going back and forth to doubles only as needed.

Answer (score 3):

> are bitwise shifts on integers "safe" in JavaScript?

Only for integers that fit within 32 bits (31+sign). Unlike, say, Python, you can't get 1<<40.

This is how the bitwise operators are defined to work by ECMA-262, even though JavaScript Numbers are actually floats. (Technically, double-precision floats, giving you 52 bits of mantissa, easily enough to cover the range of a 32-bit int.)

There is no issue of 'endianness' involved in bitwise arithmetic, and no byte-storage format where endianness could be involved is built into JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript doesn't have an integer type, only a floating point type. You can never get close enough to the implementation details to worry about this.

Comment: This is no longer accurate.  Endian does matter.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Uint16Array